# Выборка из массива JS, jQuery

Tags: jquery, массивы, выборка

Помогите сделать выборку из массива так, что-бы цифры из массива не повторялись в классах. То есть для каждого класса свое число из массива каждые 10 секунд и каждый раз по разному.

```
setInterval(function(){

    var numbs = [700, 1400, 2100, 2800, 3500, 4200];
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbs.length);

    $(".creation").fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".sheriff").delay(numbs[rand]).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".tv-tower").delay(numbs[rand]).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".mart").delay(numbs[rand]).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".mail").delay(numbs[rand]).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".market").delay(numbs[rand]).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".bath").delay(numbs[rand]).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);

}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){

    var numbs = [700, 1400, 2100, 2800, 3500, 4200];

    function getValueFromArray() {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbs.length);
      var result = numbs[randomIndex];
      numbs.splice(randomIndex, 1);
      return result;
    }

    $(".creation").fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".sheriff").delay(getValueFromArray()).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".tv-tower").delay(getValueFromArray()).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".mart").delay(getValueFromArray()).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".mail").delay(getValueFromArray()).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".market").delay(getValueFromArray()).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".bath").delay(getValueFromArray()).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);

}, 10000);
```

Демонстрация:

```js
    setInterval(function (){
    
        var numbs = [700, 1400, 2100, 2800, 3500, 4200];
    
        function getValueFromArray() {
          var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbs.length);
          var result = numbs[randomIndex];
          numbs.splice(randomIndex, 1);
          return result;
        }
    
        var temp = [];
        while (numbs.length > 0)
          temp.push(getValueFromArray());

        console.log(temp);
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: числа иногда совпадают, а как сделать так что-бы вообще не совпадали?

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Когда нужно очистишь интервал

```js
var i = 0;
var numbs = [700, 1400, 2100, 2800, 3500, 4200];
setInterval(function(){
        
    var b = numbs.slice(i).concat(numbs.slice(0,i));
    $(".creation").fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".sheriff").delay(b[0]).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".tv-tower").delay(b[1]).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".mart").delay(b[2]).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".mail").delay(b[3]).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".market").delay(b[4]).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    $(".bath").delay(b[5]).fadeIn(500).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    i++;
}, 10000);
```